# Reference request for non-perturbative QCD

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics, non-perturbative

I am looking for some good books or lecture notes that discuss non-perturbative aspects of QCD such as: chiral symmetry and chiral symmetry breaking; the QCD phase transition and the QCD phase diagram; quark confinement and flux tubes; the QCD vacuum; the trace anomaly, chiral anomalies and anomaly cancellation.

The contents of the [notes by John Preskill](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/notes.html#qcd) are the kind of thing I'm looking for, but the formatting of the notes is something of an obstacle for me. I'm surprised I haven't seen some kind of standard text on this subject, since questions like the nature of the proton and how the gluons bind the quarks together seem so fundamental. But I've not been to a QFT course where these things have been properly discussed. So if there is a standard text or any particularly good books or notes, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the 2nd volume by Weinberg and Witten's lectures "Dynamical Aspects of QFT" in "Quantum Fields and Strings: a Course for Mathematicians" (his lectures are not actually for mathematicians, don't worry).

Answer (score 0):

Despite its age, I like the thin book by Thony Thomas and Wolfram Weise "The structure of the Nucleon" (Wiley-VCH, 2001).
 It also contains a concise chapter on "Elements on QCD" but in general it is a gentle introduction to the field without a lot of technical details or heavy math.